# Is there a way to remove default column names when processing data in azure synapse analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am currently calling an API and storing the files on the cloud (which are CSVs), however whenever I export these files, they always have

`Prop_1 Prop_2 Prop_3`
instead of
`Column_1 Column_2 Column_3`

I have these selected these options for my integration dataset [image: picture]

Comment: Can you add your pipeline JSON? I think the above is configurations of your sink csv file. How your source schema is generating from API?

Comment: It should automatically scan the CSV

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go to the import schema tab and reimport the schema and see if it helps